# center items within vue router link

Tags: css, vue.js

I would like to create a navigation bar with `router-link` items. Each navigation item should have an icon on the left side and a text on the right side.

An example would be the Firebase navigation bar

[image]

My own navigation bar looks like this

[image]

and as you can see items are not centered vertically. I created a small fiddle to show my code, the only important file is **Navbar.vue**

https://codesandbox.io/s/31jw7ql3ym

When I remove the icon the text gets centered well. How can I keep both items centered when adding the icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with flex by adding this to the parent element:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
```

In your case, by adding it to `a` element:

Your code in *Navbar.vue*

```
a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #b2b4b8;
  transition-property: color, background;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `vertical-align` property to achieve that in css

```
.material-icons{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is fine. Links 2 - 5 look good but link one looks weird. https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/165027329981153280/545917984011452416/unknown.png